# regex pattern for alphanumeric+special characters

Tags: regex

I want to know the regex pattern for alphanumeric+special characters. Conditions are:

1. This pattern should allow alphanumeric characters + special characters.
2. Special characters can come with combination of other alphanumeric characters not alone.
3. Alphanumeric characters can be alone(without special characters).
4. First character can be special or alphanumeric.

Comment: i tried something like "\^[A-Za-z0-9]+[@#&]+$"

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want this:

```
^(?=.*?[a-zA-Z\d])[\w@#&*+=-]+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/qW3oQ8/1

Comment: will it satisfy the above conditions?

Comment: I am somehow confused about your conditions. If you gave examples what should and what shouldn't match, all of this would be easier.

Comment: Allowed: 1. Abc*+=-_ 2. Abc 3. *hg8

Comment: Not allowed: special char alone are not allowed like 1. *+ etc. But they can be in combination with characters like *+dfg